# Running two different SQL queries in a single nodejs function

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I've got a query with two tables. The stockmaster table comes in second after the prodstock table. Now that I want to update both tables by running two queries, I want to run a query using a function, but I can't, as I will explain in more detail below.

**This is stockmaster table**

[image: this is first table]

**This is prodstock table**

[image]

here is the code of the function

```
    export const postStock = (body) => {
    let sql = ` INSERT INTO stockmaster (stocknum, cat_id, user_id, dyenumber, stockQty, price,stockform, remark) VALUES ('${body.stocknum}', '${body.cat_id}', '${body.user_id}', '${body.dyenumber}', '${body.stockQty}', '${body.price}', '${body.stockform}', '${body.remark}')`;
    return sql;   
};

export const updateprodStock = (cat_id, dyenumber, stockQty) => {
    let sql = `UPDATE prodstock JOIN stockmaster ON prodstock.cat_id = '${cat_id}' AND prodstock.dyenumber = '${dyenumber}' SET prodstock.total_qty = prodstock.total_qty + '${stockQty} `
    return sql}
```

and here where both function are called

```
static stock = (req, res) => {
        const { cat_id, dyenumber, stockQty } = req.body;
        connection.query(postStock(req.body), (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            } else {
                connection.query(updateprodStock(cat_id, dyenumber, stockQty))
                res.status(200).json({
                    code: 1,
                    msg: "success",
                    data: result
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

So, in order for the stock to be updated and the total quantity to be updated in one function, I also want to run the updateprodStock command when I perform the poststock function. However, this is not working. Can anyone offer assistance?

Comment: this job is better made in triggers on the server. where every INSERT or UPDATE will change the stock

Comment: ya that's why i am stuck here because i have to trigger update query of prodstock table whenever the stockmaster will update.

Comment: that really doesn't matter the trogger will take care of i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Here I solved this problem by myself I have to call just another query under the first query using function now it looks like following and successfully working it is as follows:-

```
static stock = (req, res) => {
  const { cat_id, dyenumber, stockQty } = req.body;
  connection.query(postStock(req.body), (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
    connection.query(updateprodStock(cat_id, dyenumber, stockQty), (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      res.status(200).send("Product Stock updated successfully")
    })
    res.status(200).json({
      code: 1,
      msg: "success",
      data: "Stock arrived successfully"
    })
  })
}
```

I just called another query into the old function and it solved everything .....

Comment: How can I use promise in this stock function ??? is anyone can help???

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this line is not perfect:

```
let sql = 'UPDATE prodstock JOIN stockmaster ON prodstock.cat_id = '${cat_id}' AND prodstock.dyenumber = '${dyenumber}' SET prodstock.total_qty = prodstock.total_qty + '${stockQty} '
```

It will be ( after adding variables):

```
UPDATE prodstock JOIN stockmaster ON prodstock.cat_id = 3 AND prodstock.dyenumber = 2 SET prodstock.total_qty = prodstock.total_qty + 1
```

You can alco consider of using bind variables insteadof literals. Anyway, this update should look like that:

```
UPDATE prodstock 
SET total_qty = prodstock.total_qty + 1
where prodstock.cat_id = 3 AND prodstock.dyenumber = 2
```

Comment: but I have to use dynamic values instead of static to update the stock of my product whenever the stock table is updated it has to update productstock table also how can I do that ??