# Nodejs Return Stop for Loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, for-loop

Here is the code, and when I run it, it only executes once...

```
export const postStock = (body) => {
    for (let val of body.order.values()) {
        let sql = ` INSERT INTO stockmaster (stocknum, cat_id, user_id, dyenumber, stockQty) VALUES ('${body.stocknum}', ${JSON.stringify(val.cat_id)}, '${body.user_id}', ${JSON.stringify(val.dyenumber)}, ${JSON.stringify(val.stockQty)})`;
        return sql;
    };
};
```

So, how do I run the for loop or prevent it from stopping?

Look at how the function works, and when the loop starts, it sends the response multiple times, so I tried to set it outside of the loop, but if I set it outside of the loop, how can I send an error in response?

So now I'm stuck here...!

```
static stock = async (req, res) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < req.body.order.length; i++) {
            const body = req.body;      
            connection.query(postStock(body, body.order[i]), (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        code: 0,
                        msg: "Fail",
                        emsg: "Server error: " + err.message
                    });
                } else {
                    connection.query(updatepStock(body.order[i]), async (err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            res.status(500).json({
                                code: 0,
                                msg: "Fail",
                                emsg: "Server error: " + err.message
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
        res.status(201).json({code: 1,msg: "success",emsg: "Stock arrived & Product Stock updated successfully"
        })
    }
```

Comment: you could add the query into a array and return the array after the loop is done.  but it is not totally clear what you need

Comment: What's the expected output you're after?

Comment: Tip: You can do bulk insert using `INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column 2) VALUES ?` and pass an array of values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73670970/i-want-to-perform-a-query-of-my-sql-with-nodejs This is my table and everything in this  i want to insert multiple data that i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this. return makes the loop function to exit.

```
  export const postStock = (body) => {
    let values =  body.order.values();
    let sql = values.map((val) => `("${body.stocknum}", 
     "${JSON.stringify(val.cat_id)}", "${body.user_id}", 
     "${JSON.stringify(val.dyenumber)}", "${JSON.stringify(val.stockQty)}")`)
     let query = "INSERT INTO stockmaster (stocknum, cat_id, user_id, dyenumber, 
       stockQty) VALUES " + sql
    }
```

Comment: maybe you are right but in nodejs map function is note working it gives error like this TypeError: values.map is not a function

Comment: what does the body.order.values() contains. can you console.log that? the error shows up if body.order.value() is not array.  make sure to only call the map method on valid arrays.

Comment: @ brook yonas that loop is solved but after loop running i have som if else statements and res.json which are getting error because of sending res twice in loop so i don't know how to figure it out

Comment: ow. so the error is caused because you call connection.end() and try to open it in the loop

Comment: Does that answer your question?? your connection.end() called before the query finished. so connection.end() should be called in the outer loop

Comment: but how can i do this i don't know can you help me ??

Answer (score 3):

`return` stops execution and exits the function. **`return` always exits** its function immediately, with no further execution if it's inside a for loop.

So you should avoid `return` in case you want the loop to continue. What you can do is store the sql into array or print the data without returning anything